# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.length')

Tags: react-native

I am very new to react-native. I just made a small app. And I wanted to add some images as introduction of app.
So I added 'react-native-app-intro-slider' module.
Then I got the following error.

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.length')

That is my `app.js`. I am not sure what the problem is.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';

const slides = [
  {
    key: 's1',
    text: 'Best Recharge offers',
    title: 'Mobile Recharge',
    image: require('./intro/(1).jpg'),
    backgroundColor: '#20d2bb',
  },
  {
    key: 's2',
    title: 'Flight Booking',
    text: 'Upto 25% off on Domestic Flights',
    image: require('./intro/(2).jpg'),
    backgroundColor: '#febe29',
  },
  {
    key: 's3',
    title: 'Great Offers',
    text: 'Enjoy Great offers on our all services',
    image: require('./intro/(3).jpg'),
    backgroundColor: '#22bcb5',
  },
];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showRealApp: false,
    };
  }
  _renderNextButton = () => {
  };
  _renderDoneButton = () => {
  };
  _onDone = () => {
    this.setState({ showRealApp: true });
  };
  _onSkip = () => {
    this.setState({ showRealApp: true });
  };
  _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.showRealApp) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>aaaaa</Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <AppIntroSlider
          slides={slides}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          onDone={this._onDone}
          showSkipButton={true}
          onSkip={this._onSkip}
          renderDoneButton={this._renderDoneButton}
          renderNextButton={this._renderNextButton}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

How to fix this error? Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake was: `slides={slides}` must be `data={slides}`.

Fixed code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';

const slides = [
  {
    key: 's1',
    text: 'Best Recharge offers',
    title: 'Mobile Recharge',
    image: require('./intro/(1).jpg'),
    backgroundColor: '#20d2bb',
  },
  {
    key: 's2',
    title: 'Flight Booking',
    text: 'Upto 25% off on Domestic Flights',
    image: require('./intro/(2).jpg'),
    backgroundColor: '#febe29',
  },
  {
    key: 's3',
    title: 'Great Offers',
    text: 'Enjoy Great offers on our all services',
    image: require('./intro/(3).jpg'),
    backgroundColor: '#22bcb5',
  },
];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showRealApp: false,
    };
  }
  _renderNextButton = () => {
  };
  _renderDoneButton = () => {
  };
  _onDone = () => {
    this.setState({ showRealApp: true });
  };
  _onSkip = () => {
    this.setState({ showRealApp: true });
  };
  _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.showRealApp) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>aaaaa</Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <AppIntroSlider
          data={slides}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          onDone={this._onDone}
          showSkipButton={true}
          onSkip={this._onSkip}
          renderDoneButton={this._renderDoneButton}
          renderNextButton={this._renderNextButton}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing data to slides. So this error appears.
Instead of "slides={slides}" it will be "data={slides}"
Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/intrigued-graham-crackers

```
<AppIntroSlider
          data={slides}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          onDone={this._onDone}
          showSkipButton={true}
          onSkip={this._onSkip}
          renderDoneButton={this._renderDoneButton}
          renderNextButton={this._renderNextButton}
        />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already solved problem with the help of Maycon.
Anyway , Thank you.

Comment: Hi All, I am getting **Can't find variable: Image**